# How can only one servlet instance exist in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

Usually, there is only one instance of a specific servlet in the container. This servlet gets reused for every request. However, by default, every servlet request runs in a different thread. How can, say, only one servlet instance that extends HttpServlet exist on two different calls to doPost(request, response)?

I want to confirm if there are two stacks using one heap for this.

Comment: No matter how many instances of `HttpServlet` you've got - every call to `doPost` will have its private stack, but all calls use one single heap. This is the same for every method call in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking for. If you have doubts about how can the same servlet instance be shared by several threads, it's almost like you instantiate an object, create a number of threads and pass the same object instance to all those threads (I don't know the servlet frameworks internals to give you a precise explanation).

Comment: What watery said. Instantiating the servlet and creating and managing the threads that access that instance is done by the Servlet container. So you don't have to worry about it. And all threads have their own stack and there is only one heap.

Comment: @isnot2bad unless we implements SingleThreadModel interface, the container may instantiate multiple instances of that servlet in each JVM of the container.

Comment: Every thread has its own stack. This has nothing to do with Servlets specifically, or even Java: it is true of every thread implementation ever devised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlets are instantiated by the Servlet container, you have no explicit control over that.

You can't force to have only 1 instance of a specific Servlet in a Servlet container (although typically this will be the case); at least not in an official way because the Servlet API does not provide any way to do it. Some container implementations might provide you an arbitrary API for this, but I wouldn't count on it.

Instead make your Servlet implementation so that it doesn't depend on how many instances there are (e.g. do not use static attributes).

**Update:**

Quoting from the [Servlet specification 2.3](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/first/jsr053/servlet23_PFD.pdf) section #2.3.1:

> It is important to note that **there can be more than one instance of a
>   given Servlet class** in the servlet container. For example, this can
>   occur where there was more than one servlet definition that utilized a
>   specific servlet class with different initialization parameters. This
>   can also occur when a servlet implements the SingleThreadModel
>   interface and the container creates a pool of servlet instances to
>   use.

Comment: Dead wrong. See Servlet Specification 2.2.

Comment: @EJP I just checked the spec and it clearly states that there can be multiple instances of a specific Servlet. Please check my updated answer and tell me why it is "Dead wrong".

Comment: It is quoted in another answer here. Unless you use SingleThreadModel, which is deprecated, 'the Servlet container must use only one instance per Servlet declaration'. Ergo if you don't use SingleThreadModel and only have one Servlet declaration, you are guaranteed to only get one instance. Ergo your first and second sentences are false. QED

Comment: Yes, if we make all boolean varialbes false and check their logical OR'ed value, it will be false.. `SingleThreadModle` might be deprecated but still can be used. On the other hand, multiple servlet declarations are not deprecated. The questioner did not narrowed down the question to a single declaration, so what I stated is true.

Comment: You don't seem to understand your own quotation, and I didn't say anything about Boolean variables, but you said that there is no way to ensure there is only one instance, and the specification provides you wrong. You're not making much sense here.

Comment: I thought the analogy will be straightforward. Yes, if you don't use certain features, you will be guaranteed with at most one Servlet instance of a specific type. If certain features are used, then you won't be guaranteed.

Comment: guys, does this apply to latest specification as well? I mean could there be multiple instances per servlet in a container?

Answer (score 5):

The [Servlet Specification #2.2](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.5-mr5-oth-JSpec/servlet-2.5-mr5-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1407985950_d793ab37fffd7941900ad52aadf5b23e) states that:

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
>   **the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet**
>   declaration. However, for a servlet implementing the SingleThreadModel
>   interface, the servlet container may instantiate multiple instances to
>   handle a heavy request load and serialize requests to a particular
>   instance.
>
> In the case where a servlet was deployed as part of an application
>   marked in the deployment descriptor as distributable, **a container may
>   have only one instance per servlet declaration per Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM)**. However, if the servlet in a distributable application
>   **implements the SingleThreadModel** interface, the container may
>   instantiate **multiple instances** of that servlet in each JVM of the
>   container.

So, do **NOT** use SingleThreadModel will make it.

Also, [Creating Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/820-1646/abxbh/index.html) states that

> By default, servlets are not thread-safe. The methods in a single
>   servlet instance are usually executed numerous times simultaneously
>   (up to the available memory limit). **Each execution occurs in a
>   different thread, though only one servlet copy exists in the servlet
>   engine.**

So, you should deal with the synchronization in your case;

Comment: Very good but please cite the source. Is it the Servlet Speification?

Comment: Yes, please check here please http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.5-mr5-oth-JSpec/servlet-2.5-mr5-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1407985950_d793ab37fffd7941900ad52aadf5b23e

Comment: Please *cite* it. A mere link isn't a citation. I've independently established that it is Java Servlet Specification section 2.2. That information should appear in your answer.

Comment: There can be more than one instance of a given Servlet class in the servlet container. See my answer for quote and source from the Servlet specification.

Comment: @icza Only if you use SingleThreadModel or provide more than one declaration.